# Populating Kivy widgets with a .csv file

Tags: python, csv, kivy

Hello everyone I need some help here I have a .csv file containing some data and I'm trying to populate some kivy widgets using the data obtained from it. So far everything runs ok but When adding the widgets I think I'm just adding them to the class instance and not the Box-layout.

this is my .csv:

```
My hero academics,fighting,midoriya
alice,test,malcolm
```

Below is my code block.

```
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.button import Button
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivy.uix.label import Label
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    from kivy.properties import ListProperty
    import csv

Builder.load_string("""
<Test>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text:'list 1'
        Label:
            text:'label 2'
"""
)

class Test(BoxLayout):
    label_value = ListProperty()
    testList= ['potato', 'jake', 'ofu', 'zach']
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(Test, self).__init__(**kw)
        testlist = open("C:/Users/zfarley/Documents/Development/python_project/kivy-app/TEST/zachList.csv").read()
        #reads in data
        zach_list = testlist.split("\n")
        item_count= 1
        for value in zach_list:
            btn= Button(text= str(value), pos=(100,10))
            label= Label(text=str(item_count) )
            item_count= item_count + 1
            #self.rows= rows
            self.add_widget(label)
            self.add_widget(btn)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()

TestApp().run()
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: Since you are splitting your input on the newline character ("\n") your zach_list will only have one element (the entire line), and it looks like you will add one button and one label to the Layout.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is the buttons that I'm adding isn't following the box layout format that I set. For example the default orientation is horizontal, however only the first 2 labels populate in a horizontal fashion. When adding the buttons to the screen its not going to my boxlayout